# How to get a EWS token that has write access from Office.js

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices, office-js

I need to set the category of mail item using EWS.

Basically I set it like so (VB code)

```
If Not outlookItem.Categories.Contains("MyCategory") Then
   outlookItem.Categories.Add("MyCategory")
   outlookItem.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite)
End If
```

This fails with an exception

> The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application.

Now, I found that this is because I'm using a token produced by the office API method [`getCallbackTokenAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox#getcallbacktokenasynccallback-usercontext) to authenticate with EWS. Apparently this token is read-only.

I am looking for suggestions for an alternative way to use outlooks credentials to authenticate with EWS. I would much prefer to work with the managed API.

Comment: You need to make use of makeEwsRequestAsync within your addin, if you enable tracing in you Managed API code you can get the exact XML you then need for that function.

Comment: but how would i obtain a changekey?

Comment: Make a GetItem request on the Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId first you should then be able to obtain the change key you need